# How to extend paging session timeout value?

Tags: paging, ptc-windchill

I am trying to use paging query on Windchill, but always get paging session timeout exeception if a sesssion lasts longer than 30 min. The method `PagingSessionHelper.extendTimeout(long sessionID)` changes nothing.

[PTC Solution](https://www.ptc.com/appserver/cs/view/solution.jsp?n=149329) says this issue has been addressed in Windchill Solutions 9.1 Maintenance Release M060, but I have the same problem when testing against Windchill 10.

Anybody knows how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Set wt.pom.paging.sessionCleanupTime to a higher value in /db/db.properties

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot change that properties file on our customer's server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can stop the commonschedulequeue temporarily to get the same result as extending the wt.pom.paging.sessionCleanupTime as that queue runs the cleanup.